# java loop runs more than expected

Tags: java, recursion, methods, while-loop

I can't figure out why my method does this :(

It's normally for creating an IBAN. It should split 123456780000123456131400 in parts with the length of 9 so it can fit in an Integer. It's working pretty fine and delivers me the right solution `58`, but I added some `System.out.println();`'s to see what happens in this method.

And it runs the if-case 8 times and sometimes it reenters the while loop, before giving me the solution :/

I think it is a problem with my recursion, but I can't really figure out why.

```
public static int rest(String r) {
    int e = 0;
    while(r.length() >= 9) {
        e = (Integer.parseInt(r.substring(0,9)) % 97);
        r = Integer.toString(e) + r.substring(9);
        rest(r);
    }
    if(r.length() < 9)
        e = (Integer.parseInt(r.substring(0)) % 97);
    return e;
```

And the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String bban = "123456780000123456131400";
    System.out.println(rest(bban));
}
```

Comment: So the code gives the right solution, but there is a problem somewhere? Hmm, sorry you will have to be more descriptive about the problem.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem, if the code gives you the right solution? What is it doing that you don't understand?

Comment: I might be missing something here, but why is the call `rest(r)` inside the while loop required? Doesn't that undo the purpose of a while loop?

Comment: You need to decide if you want recursion or iteration. For example, change the while to if and see if you get the correct answer...then ask how come?

Comment: You're doing two different things here that are making this more complex than it should be: looping and recursion. You should pick one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated, you can either have a while-loop or a recursion. 
As well as the result of `rest(r)` isn't ever returned. So it's doing a useless recursion with no used result and the while-loop on the first level returns `e` for the last 9-er block.

I don't know the IBAN logic behind that, but your function is only returning  the `%97` fro the last 9-er block:

With recursion:

```
public static int rest(String r) {

     if (r.length() >= 9) {
        int e = (Integer.parseInt(r.substring(0,9)) % 97);
        r = Integer.toString(e) + r.substring(9);
        return rest(r);
     }
     if(r.length() < 9)
        return (Integer.parseInt(r.substring(0)) % 97);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks to all of you! First I wanted to Iterate, then to do a recursion, so I mixed It up :S We started Programming a week ago, so im not very good at using recursive-calls. But this is working as expected, I changed the second if-case to else, so It doesn't argue with me for a missing return statement.

Comment: I can't edit my first comment so sorry! My logic behind that was to split the 24 digit string into a Integer friendly 9 digit. So 123456780000123456131400 -> 123456780 % 97 = **30** -> **30**0001234 % 97 = **22** -> **22**5613140 = **64** -> **64**0 = **58** with that I should get the rest of the whole 24 digit one